# Why my function hide/show element base on radio button not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why my function hide/show element base on radio button not work ?

http://jsfiddle.net/qmzz9x7h/

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
            if($(#radio_id).attr("value")=="first"){
                $("#second_checkbox").hide();                
                $("#first_checkbox_display").show();
            }
            if($(#radio_id).attr("value")=="second"){
                $("#first_checkbox_display").hide();                
                $("#second_checkbox").show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i want to check value from radio button `id="radio_id"`

Comment: You use a double id for the radio item. Group radiobuttons by using the same name, not the same ID

Comment: you have duplicate id's `radio_id` in your html which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".radio_id").click(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="first"){
                $("#second_checkbox").hide();                
                $("#first_checkbox_display").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="second"){
                $("#first_checkbox_display").hide();                
                $("#second_checkbox").show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Give your radio button a class "radio_id"

Answer (score 2):

your fiddle is wrong, take look on short and improved version:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(e){
        var _val = $(this).val();
        var _id = $(this).attr('id'); // Grap the ID

        $("#second_checkbox, #first_checkbox_display").hide(); 

        console.log(_val);
        if( _val == "first" ){
            $("#"+_val+"_checkbox_display").show();
        }
        else if( _val =="second"){    
            $("#"+_val+"_checkbox").show();
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/jmxaug60/)

Comment: i want to use id of radio button `id="radio_id"` too.